# Reset link's background colour with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With jQuery, I'm currently changing the background colour of my link when it's clicked. However, I'd like to reset this colour once a) I close the link or b) I click another link (say `Dropdown 2`).

Can someone assist with this? Would I use `toggle`?

https://jsfiddle.net/ot3g0aw0/

```js
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){
        
      //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).css('background-color','red').next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

```css
  .accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
  .sub-menu {display: none;}
  .sub-menu .sub-menu {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="medium-8 columns primary menu">
<ul class="inline naked">
    <li class="primary-item"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress">Home</a></li>      
 <li id="menu-item-74" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-74"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 1</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu">
   <li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-76"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=45">Dropdown </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li id="menu-item-77" class="sub-sub-menu menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-77"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=47">Test 1</a></li>
                    <li id="menu-item-78" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-78"><a href="http://localhost:8888/test/wordpress/?page_id=49">Test 2</a></li>
    </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>    
        <li id="menu-item-79" class="primary-item menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-79"><a href="#" class="navtoggle">Dropdown 2</a></li>
 </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: I suggest you use plain css active and visited seletor. [Much faster than js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be easier to use a class to set the background, then you can just toggle the class using [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle the selected state

```
.selected {background-color: red;}
```

then

```
  $(document).ready(function($) {
    var $toggles = $('.inline').find('.navtoggle').click(function(){
        $toggles.not(this).removeClass('selected')

      //Expand or collapse this panel
        $(this).toggleClass('selected').next().slideToggle('fast');

      //Hide the other panels
      $(".sub-menu").not($(this).next()).slideUp('fast');

    });
  });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/x3ak0ueg/)